# Unable to execute adb commands from android studio, espresso tests but able to run them from terminal

Tags: android

Throws the below error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps": error=13, Permission denied
i used the code below from Android studio , espresso tests.

```
String cmd = "adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

adb shell runs on your PC. Try taking that off and just run "settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps".

Another option is to separate all blank-delimited strings into arguments, e.g:

new ProcessBuilder(cmd, arg1, arg2, arg3...);